# optimizing jquery code for animating actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, jquery-animate, simplify

I'm taking my first steps in jquery, and I've written my first piece of code for animating picture galleries. The thing is:

1. I have some cover pics and the related content divs, which are hidden (height: 0;).
2. Each time one cover pic is clicked, the related div opens (changing the height value).
3. If it the related div is already opened, it closes. If another related div is opened,  it closes and opens the correct div.
4. If the "close" button is clicked, it closes the current open div.

The code is working perfectly, but I couldn't find a syntax that can be placed just once. The way it is now, I have to repeat the script for each new "cover pic / content div" (g1/lg1 g2/lg2 g3/lg3 - in the example), specifying the selector.

How can I make it work specifying just one pair of selectors for all cover pics and related content div?

Here it goes the code: (http://jsfiddle.net/samuelleal/9PL3S/3/)

```
$(function () {

    $('.close').click(function () {
        if ($(this).parent().height() > 0) {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('open').animate({
                height: "0px"
            }, 500);
        } else {}
    });

    $('.lg1').click(function () {
        if ($('.g1').height() > 0) {
            $('.g1').removeClass('open').animate({
                height: "0px"
            }, 500);
        } else {
            $('.gallery:not(.g1)').removeClass('open').animate({
                height: "0px"
            }, 500, function () {
                $('.g1').addClass('open').animate({
                    height: "80px"
                }, 500);
            });
        }
    });

    $('.lg2').click(function () {
        if ($('.g2').height() > 0) {
            $('.g2').removeClass('open').animate({
                height: "0px"
            }, 500);
        } else {
            $('.gallery:not(.g2)').removeClass('open').animate({
                height: "0px"
            }, 500, function () {
                $('.g2').addClass('open').animate({
                    height: "80px"
                }, 500);
            });
        }
    });

    $('.lg3').click(function () {
        if ($('.g3').height() > 0) {
            $('.g3').removeClass('open').animate({
                height: "0px"
            }, 500);
        } else {
            $('.gallery:not(.g3)').removeClass('open').animate({
                height: "0px"
            }, 500, function () {
                $('.g3').addClass('open').animate({
                    height: "80px"
                }, 500);
            });
        }
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<body id="body">
<div id="strip" class="f4">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="lg1 pics orange" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="lg2 pics red" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="lg3 pics green" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="gallery g1">
        <div class="close blue">close</div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="pics orange"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="pics orange"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="pics orange"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="pics orange"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="pics orange"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery g2">
        <div class="close blue">close</div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="pics red"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="pics red"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="pics red"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="pics red"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="pics red"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery g3">
        <div class="close blue">close</div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="pics green"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="pics green"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="pics green"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="pics green"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="pics green"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.pics, li {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.green {
    background-color: darkgreen;
}
.blue {
    background-color: darkblue;
}
.red {
    background-color: darkred;
}
.orange {
    background-color: darkorange;
}
.close {
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0 5px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#strip > ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    display: block;
}
.gallery {
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: gray;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Do not use the same ID on multiple elements.

Comment: Are you talking about the #gallery divs? I'm using it for styling, and it could be changed for classes, indeed. Yet, it doesn't solve the problem, since the javascript still would have to refer to each gallery in multiple instances.

Comment: Yeah, the gallery divs. Do change to classes and make your HTMl valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with techfoobar, that you shouldn't have multiple identical IDs on different elements, so I modified that for my answer (you *could* technically do it with classes, I suppose...). After changing the IDs to the classes and the classes to the IDs for the Gallery class elements (and modifying the corresponding CSS), you can give each colored square a 'gallery' attribute (to point to which gallery it opens) and attach a click event handler to all of your colored squares which looks to that gallery attribute to find which one to display:

```
$(document).on('click','#strip ul li div',function(){
    var gallery = $(this).attr('gallery');
    if ($('#'+gallery).height() > 0) {
        $('#'+gallery).removeClass('open').animate({
            height: "0px"
        }, 500);
    } else {
        $('.gallery:not(#'+gallery+')').removeClass('open').animate({
            height: "0px"
        }, 500, function () {
            $('#'+gallery).addClass('open').animate({
                height: "80px"
            }, 500);
        });
    }
  });
```

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/Qv9KR/1/

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing (except the use of the custom gallery attribute, which is a nice approach). Only changes I'd suggest are caching the gallery element, e.g. `var galleryElement = $('#'+gallery);` and, instead of using `'.gallery:not()`, instead say `galleryElement.siblings().removeClass('open')`, which is cleaner and I believe a bit more efficient.  (You'd have to wrap the .gallery elements in a containing div, though, that belonged only to them, for `.siblings` to work.)